# WPF MVVM Doubts

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hello fellow StackOverflow users (or *Stackoverflowers*?):

I'm learning-by-coding WPF. I read several articles/saw several screencasts, and coming from a WEB dev background, I fired up VS2010 and started doing a sample application that would help me learn the basics.

I read some about MVVM too, and started using it. I set up my solution to use WPF 4.0, ActiveRecord 2.1 and SQLite, and everything went kind well. But I still have some doubts:

- I created a MainWindowViewModel, and am using the RelayCommand class from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) to... relay the command. Am I breaking any guidelines by having a MenuItem from the MainWindow to have its command bound to a property of this viewmodel?
- This action I'm binding the MenuItem command to is going to instantiate a new ViewModel and a new View, and show it. Again, is that ok in the MVVM context?
- My MainWindow will be a kind of "dashboard", and I will have more than one model attached to this dashboard. Should I just wrap all those models in a single view model?

Something like this:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel {

    private ObservableCollection<Order> openOrders;
    private Address deliveryAddress;
    private Order newOrder;
    /* Wrappers for the OpenOrders Collection */
    /* Wrappers for Delivery Address */
    /* Wrappers for New Order */
    /* Command Bindings */

}
```

TIA!

Comment: Some people refer to the StackOverflow users as Stackers

Comment: @Eduardo, wtaniguchi: see [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/what-should-the-users-of-stack-overflow-be-called) on meta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I created a MainWindowViewModel, and am using the RelayCommand class from here to... relay the command. Am I breaking any guidelines by having a MenuItem from the MainWindow to have its command bound to a property of this viewmodel?

No, you're not breaking any guideline. It's perfectly appropriate to bind the MenuItem to a command of the MainWindowViewModel (where else would you put this command anyway ?)

> This action I'm binding the MenuItem command to is going to instantiate a new ViewModel and a new View, and show it. Again, is that ok in the MVVM context?

It's perfectly fine to create a new ViewModel, of course. As for creating a new view, it depends on how you create it... you should of course *never* instantiate a view explicitly from the ViewModel, because it would introduce a dependency of the VM to the view.

> My MainWindow will be a kind of "dashboard", and I will have more than one model attached to this dashboard. Should I just wrap all those models in a single view model?

It depends on what you mean by "wrap"... Your `MainWindowViewModel` could expose other ViewModels through properties, and theses VMs would be displayed in different parts of the view. If that's what you mean, yes, you should wrap them.

Comment: thanks for your response. For the second answer, I was thinking exacly about that when asking the question. Assuming I wouldn't explicitly call "new SomeView();", how should I call another view from within a viewmodel? About the third answer, I would need to expose the ViewModels I would need for different parts of the View, and use a UserControl + a ResourceDictionary to render that type, and bind the exposed VM to it?

Comment: For the 2nd point, I typically use a ContentControl that picks the appropriate DataTemplate based on the type of the viewmodel. For the 3rd: yes, exactly

Comment: Ok! Thanks! I think I have a better understanding now, and will work my thoughts around this issues!

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the Thomas answer:

I would create different usercontrols for each part of the dashboard and assign a viewModel to each usercontrol.

Answer (score 2):

> I created a MainWindowViewModel, and am using the RelayCommand class from here to... relay the command. Am I breaking any guidelines by having a MenuItem from the MainWindow to have its command bound to a property of this viewmodel?

No, that's exactly where you put commands.

> This action I'm binding the MenuItem command to is going to instantiate a new ViewModel and a new View, and show it. Again, is that ok in the MVVM context?

It shouldn't need to know how to instantiate a new view; that's the view's job.  The specifics of how to do this depend on how you're showing this new view - it could be as simple as having a ContentPresenter in the view that's bound to a property in the view model, so when you set the property (and raise PropertyChanged) the ContentPresenter renders the new object with its related DataTemplate.

Things get a little hinky if by "instantiate a new view" you mean "open a new window."  There's not an especially elegant way to do this, especially if you want the new window to be a modal dialog.  One way is to add an event handler to the view's code-behind that listens to PropertyChanged on the view model; when the subordinate view model property gets set, the code in the view creates and shows the new window.

> My MainWindow will be a kind of "dashboard", and I will have more than one model attached to this dashboard. Should I just wrap all those models in a single view model?

Sure.  That's a really common pattern.  It's not at all uncommon, for instance, to expose an observable collection property and bind an ItemsControl of some kind to it; the view will automagically create views for every view model you put in that collection.  Again, the specific implementation really depends on your application.